# Visual C++ 2008 can't include its own static library

Tags: visual-c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have two projects: a **static library** and a **DLL** that will link statically to this static library. Let's assume:

```
foo.lib (static library)
bar.dll (links against foo.lib)
```

foo.lib has the following function:

```
fooFile(...);
```

I successfully built the statically lib and dumpbin /symbols tells me that the function is there (although with some name mangling). When trying to link it against the bar.dll project, I get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fooFile referenced in function _fooSomething
```

Why is this failing? The same code works without issues in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bar.dll project is compiled as C, or else includes foo.lib's headers under `extern "C" {...}`. Essentially, one project exports the function as having C++ linkage, while the other tries to import it with C linkage.

Comment: I forgot Visual C++ uses C++ as default :)